# With CDI, for a statefull EJB without a view, what scope should I use?

Tags: ejb, cdi

I must create a statefull service, with stateful EJB, but without any view (so, no http request, no http session). This service is going to be used via direct API call only.

I would like to be able to inject  objets that matches the life cycle of the stateful EJB (for exemple, the user call a 'login' method of the EJB, and I would like to be able to inject the username in the beans used in subsequent calls to the service).

Am I supposed to create my own custom Scope, or, is the use case 'view-less statefull EJB scope' somehow already handled by CDI ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to keep state in the bean? w/o access to the session then things are a little difficult to use. You could create your own scope & context. You'll need to figure out where to store the context and how long it lasts.

Comment: Well, in my case, the user session is the EJB itself, there is not a WAR involved to manage an HTTP session. Only EJB are involved here. So, OK, it seems I'll have to create a custom scope & context. Thanks.